# Windows7 + Dell D830 = frequent blue screens

Tags: windows-7, crash, bsod, minidumps

I'm using Windows 7 on a Dell laptop (Latitude D380).

The laptop used to be incredibly stable on Windows XP, but now I experience frequent blue screens (with a message saying "MEMORY DUMP") when I open a lot of applications concurrently.

Is there a way to diagnose the issue and track it down? It could be some incompatible drivers or application.

I checked the folder C:\Windows\Minidump and I found some files. THen I tried to open them and they disappeared.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are utilities such as Blue Screen View (free!) that you can download.  Google for it or one of the others and run them and they will open the minidump files and show the contents and what they believe may have triggered the crash.  Without knowing the exact error message, it would be speculation on what is causing your problem.

Comment: [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html)