# What is causing my newly built PC with Windows 7 to BSOD?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, bsod, clone, minidumps

I recently built my own PC from parts and installed Windows 7 and I have been getting [BSODs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Screen_of_Death) with various different stop codes.

The latest was `0x24`, but I've also had `0xd1` and `0x1e`. However, Windows does not let me know where the fault occurred, so I have no idea how to go about resolving this.

I know the cause is likely a hardware driver, but I don't know which and cannot find information about how to use the minidumps to troubleshoot my problem.

I've uploaded the [last three minidumps](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B6V3ayjTEtwaZDhhZDQ3NmEtNTg1Yi00OGMyLTg5YjUtZjM4ZGVkODBiNzIx&hl=en) in case someone can make sense out of them and let me know what could be causing my BSODs.

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: All three mini dumps point to different causes, suspect a bad memory module.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is still an issue for you but I would also run [MemTest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) on the system to verify that RAM is ok. Often random BSOD's like this are from a bad stick somewhere.

Comment: Had a very similar issue back in 2001 with Win2K on custom built hardware (purchased and assembled by yours truly). 

Twas then I learned about memtest86, and the usefulness of pre-assembled, burn-tested hardware (ie, it's sometimes worth the markup if your time is valuable)

Answer (score 0):

blue screen view looks super useful.
Blackbeagle recommended it under this post:

[Windows7 + Dell D830 = frequent blue screens](https://superuser.com/questions/140927/windows7-dell-d830-frequent-blue-screens)

If that does not help, I would try some of the recommendations made under this post:

[what to do if a computer gets a blue screen when trying to install windows xp](https://superuser.com/questions/145734/what-to-do-if-a-computer-gets-a-blue-screen-when-trying-to-install-windows-xp/145754#145754)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I have more info now thanks to BlueScreenView, I'll post another question with more specifics if I can't get this system working.